# How can I pass params through react-navigation module without navigate to other page?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using react-navigation module to implement the bottom tab bar, and now I want to pass the parameters to page B during the operation in page A without page jumping, is there any way to achieve this?

I read the official documentation of react-navigation, and it seems that only the navigation.navigation method can pass parameters across pages, but this will cause page jumps

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is not possible. Route params are exactly that: params passed during navigation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [AsyncStorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage) package. Save the data you will use on PageB with a key on PageA. Then get saved data on the PageB.

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

export default PageA = ({ navigation }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.setItem("PageParams", "something")
  }, [])

  return (
    <Button title='Navigate' onPress={() => navigation.navigate("PageB")} />
  );
};
```

```js
import { View } from 'react-native';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

export default PageB = () => {

  useEffect(async () => {
    const params = await AsyncStorage.getItem("PageParams")
    console.log(params) // output: something
  })

  return (
    <View />
  );
};
```